# C++ libcurl multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, libcurl

I'm trying to build a small multithreading program which takes a subdomains and test them if they are alive on http or https, I've problem that's my program doesn't produce the correct output each time I get different output and also freeze and doesn't continue execution. I followed http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/thread/ when implementing the multithreading.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[] )
{
  if (argc < 2){
    cout << "Usage httplive <path to subdomains>" << endl;
  }
  ifstream http(argv[1]);
  string line;
  vector <std::thread> thread_pool;

  while (getline(http, line)){
      thread_pool.push_back(thread(httpTest,line, true));
      thread_pool.push_back(thread(httpTest, line, false));
  }

  for (auto& t : thread_pool){
      t.join();
  }


  return 0;
}

void httpTest(string line,  bool Flag){

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode res;
    if (curl) {

      line = Flag ?  "https://" + line : "http://"+ line;
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, const_cast<char*>(line.c_str()));
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
      // curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1L);
      res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
      // cout << res << endl;
      if (res == CURLE_OK ) cout << line << endl;

  }

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);


}
```

Comment: If you add `thread_pool.reserve(10)` after your declaration does the problem go away?

Comment: I'll try it now , P.S it doesn't work I get the same behavior

Comment: Does libCURL support multithreading access? Or concurrent access, maybe parallel if your cpu has more than 1 core.

Comment: You should probably try to verify your pgrsms correctness without threads first before you try to use them. That would tell you if threading was the issue or not.

Comment: Yes I read through there doc that they support multithreading access, If I'd in parallel which library I should use